# Two sub-figures side by side but at extreme ends

Tags: floats, subfloats

I want to place two figures side by side but at extreme ends, i.e. first subfigure should be at the extreme left and the second subfigure should be at extreme right. How can this be done? I am using the code shown below

```
    \begin{figure}[htp!]
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
           \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{x.png}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
           \raggedright
           \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{y.png}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Put a `\hfill` after the first `\end{subfigure}`.

Comment: Oh, and merry Christmas!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is solved by @Skillmon comment.

Comment: @Skillmon  please let me know if any objection to my answer below--the OP has not commented yet or accepted the comment neither the answer below

Comment: @jsbibra I don't have any objections against your answer. But I decided to add my own anyways, and provide a bit of background information in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In (La)TeX you can include lengths of flexible width, so called skips, and you can stretch and shrink them by orders of infinity. A `\hfill` behaves as a skip of 0pt width but which stretches with a second order of infinity, so it will take as much space as available (as long as there are no other `\hfill`s in the same horizontal box). So we can use `\hfill` to separate your `subfigure`s as much as possible in that line.

**EDIT** Appending and building on the information provided in [@JohnKormylo's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521802/two-sub-figures-side-by-side-but-at-extreme-ends/521847?noredirect=1#comment1319754_521847):

The orders of infinity are `fil`, `fill`, and `filll` (from lowest to highest, there is also `fi`, but that is practically never used and only available in Lua(La)TeX). Normally package and kernel code should sparsely use second or third order infinity and stick to `fil`, so that users can easily overrule those. This is, e.g., true for `\parfillskip`, which gets appended at the end of every paragraph to set the last line ragged, and normally has the value `0pt plus 1fil`. If you now used `\hfil` (which is equivalent to `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil`) you'd not push the second image to the end of the line, but only use half the available space, the other half gets filled by `\parfillskip`. That's why we need to at least use second order infinity (which is infinitely larger than first order) and use `\hfill`.

`\hfilll` isn't defined by the way, and you'd have to use `\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}` (or `\hskip 0pt plus 1filll`).

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, page=1]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A pizza duck}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
    \raggedright
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, page=4]{example-image-duck-portrait}
    \caption{A clairvoyant duck}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Ducks}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might mention that \hfill overwhelms \parfillskip, but \hfil and \parfillskip expand to the same size.

Comment: @JohnKormylo good point (well this actually depends on the value of `\parfillskip`, but with standard settings this holds).

Comment: Command  `\raggedright` in the second sub figure is superfluous ;-)

Comment: @Zarko only if one uses `width=\linewidth`, but OP used `scale=0.35`, which might result in `\raggedright` being useful, that's why I didn't remove it.

Comment: @Skillmon, ok. however, use of `scale=...` can be problematic. I would discourage OP to use it and encourage to use `width=\linewidth,\keepaspectratio` instead (and than remove`raggedright` :-) )

Comment: @Zarko there is a backslash too much in that comment. Also go ahead and tell OP in the comments to the question.

Comment: @Skillmon, you are right. correct is `width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio`!

Answer (score 2):

With regards to @Skillmon comment

Although `subfig` and `subfigure` packages are deprecated and shouldn’t be used any more. Note: `subfig` support `hyperref` with BUGS!

```
\usepackage{subfig} 
... 
\begin{figure}[!ht] 
  \subfloat[Picture 1\label{fig:1}]{% 
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{1.png} 
  } 
  \hfill 
  \subfloat[Picture 2\label{fig:2}]{% 
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{2.png} 
  } 
  \caption{Main figure caption} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: As fa as I understand the question, OP have only a problem, which is solved by @Skillmon  comment. It will be nice, if you ask him first, if he is willing to convert it to an answer, otherwise, problem is solved by comment.

Comment: While it is true that the `subfigure` package is deprecated, it is *not true* that the `subfig` package is deprecated.

Comment: Since the OP uses the `subcaption` package (which isn't deprecated either) I don't understand this answer...